# Android: Frame animation on Swipe Gesture

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a custom Android Switch with swipe gesture to change the frame of images on imageview. I don't want to use Android Default switch which is not relevant according to design I have with me.

More Specifically:

A switch,
User can swipe in either direction on which I want to change the frame
,Touch and hold to pause the animation according to the scrolled position from a list of images.